# How to treat the list of exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I am looping through few routines and due to any reason these routines can throw exception. I am collecting exception from each iteration and saving in a dictionary. After finishing all iteration, I want to throw collected exception  together with iteration information. From my past experience, I know that exception messages are usually toolong and I would like to know that is there an elegant way to throw these exception and display them in a nice way.

```
static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
  Dictionary<int, Exception> exceptionDict = new Dictionary<int, Exception>( );
  for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    try {
      if( i == 0 ) {
        throw new Exception( "test0" );
      }
      else if( i == 1 ) {
        throw new Exception( "test1" );
      }
      else {
        throw new Exception( "test" );
      }
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) {
      exceptionDict.Add( i, ex );
    }
  }
  if( exceptionDict.Count > 0 ) {

    Exception ex = new AggregateException( exceptionDict.Values.ToList( )) ;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText( @"..\err.txt", ex.InnerException.StackTrace.ToString () );
    throw ex;

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to know in what iteration the exception occurred?

Comment: `"exception messages are usually too long" ... "and display them in a nice way"` - Those two statements should tell you something. Exceptions *are* indeed quite long, and they contain a *lot* of very useful information.  But it's not necessarily information to be *displayed* to the user.  The application should log exception data, but should display something simple and user-friendly to the user.  Ideally that message wouldn't reveal underlying implementation details (which can potentially be exploited) like exceptions do.

Comment: Is your question more about the throwing part or the displaying part?

Comment: I got answer of one part of my question, how to throw list of exceptions.However I do not know how will 5 or 6 exceptions will look like on dialog box? I am thinking to display Source property of Exception or message property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AggregateException. Here is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Basically throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

where exceptions is `IEnumerable<Exception>`

Comment: How this helps to treat exceptions somehow?

Comment: throw new AggregateException(exceptions)

Comment: OP wants to "display exceptions in nice way". "One or more errors occurred" isn't a nice way, IMO.

Comment: It is the right way. You could even have a custom Exception which contains custom messages with all the data you want that gets added to the aggregate.

Comment: No, it is totally wrong way. User shouldn't see any exceptions. Especially, `AggregateException`

Comment: Using AggregateException could well be distracting: the main purpose of AggregateException is to be thrown in the Tasks

Comment: "AggregateException is used to consolidate multiple failures into a single, throwable exception object." MSDN. Yes it is used my tasks but its not task specific

Comment: Murdock answers "how to throw", Dennis focus on "how to display". The two topics are orthogonal.

Comment: @Dennis "elegant way to throw these exception and display them in a nice way". This is an elegant way to throw exceptions. How he handles the exceptions is up to him. He could display the message in the exception or some custom message.

Comment: @Murdock: I added some example code, please check it. I am just getting information about first exception in err.txt file.

Comment: AggregateException ex = new AggregateException(exceptionDict.Values.ToList());System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"..\err.txt", string.Join("\n",ex.InnerExceptions.Select(o=>o.StackTrace.ToString())));